# PHP: Extensionless URLs in IIS7 (windows)? (for wordpress)

Tags: windows, iis, php, iis-7, rewrite

I have recently installed wordpress  but i would like to configure extensionless URLs .. I am using IIS7 but on a shared server.

I presume i cna add something to web.config file??

I am little bit confused, in IIS7 and asp.net mvc it is done via code... but in PHP i don't think it is .... so the only alternative is to use a re-write module but i can't as I am on  a shared server and can't install ISAPI stuff..

so I was wondering if there is a way to do the mapping i.e.  when going to testme it would actually load testme.php

Any advise really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Windows hosting myself, but this guy seems to have given the answer to your question:  http://robboek.com/2009/01/03/using-wordpress-on-iis7/

Answer (score 1):

This depends. You can use the URL Rewriter and it isn't ISAPI. It is executed in the integrated pipeline in the *BeginRequest* event. Your shared hosting provider may allow you to use the URL rewriting module. If they have, then you can add the following to your web.config under the  node:

You can find more detailed information on Ruslan's blog here:
http://ruslany.net/2009/05/iis-7-url-rewrite-module-support-in-wordpress-28/

If you don't have access to this you can use any number of additional modules, assuming you have the authority to add one to the  section. I would add additional links but because I'm new and my reputation on this site isn't up yet, I can't give you additional links.